# I want to change the divs rgb value in my website. For example I want to change value of red. How can I do it? Here is an example of my try

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the divs rgb value in my website. For example I want to change value of red. How can I do it? Here is an example of my try.
I tried to change the red color value of div I named divcolor. But It didn't work.

```js
let divcolor = document.getElementById('divcolor');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

function changeColor() {
    let redval = 0;
    let green = 0;
    let blue = 0;
    let color = 'rgb('+redval+","+green+","+blue+')';
    document.getElementById("divcolor").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function minusred() {
    redval += 100
}


button.addEventListener("click",minusred, changeColor);
```

```css
#divcolor {
    float:left;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <button id="button">hdsfs</button>
    <div id="divcolor">hellomf</div>
```

Comment: why you calling 2 function ? try to call one function at once or can use callback banction. see example
`button.addEventListener("click", changeColor);`

Comment: @okeyci-reis Please try this:
  let divcolor = document.getElementById('divcolor');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
var redval=0;
var green = 0;
var blue = 0;
function changeColor() {
    redval += 100;
    let color = 'rgb('+redval+","+green+","+blue+')';
    alert(color);
    document.getElementById("divcolor").style.backgroundColor = color;
   
}
button.addEventListener("click",changeColor);

Comment: Thank you @Ashish! This worked. I think my mistake was not using variables.

Comment: You're welcome. Please green-tick the commented code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let divcolor = document.getElementById('divcolor'); 
 let button = document.getElementById('button'); 
 var redval=0; 
 var green = 0; 
 var blue = 0; 
 function changeColor() {
 redval += 100; 
 let color = 'rgb('+redval+","+green+","+blue+')';
 document.getElementById("divcolor").style.backgroundColor = color;
 }
 button.addEventListener("click",changeColor);
```

Comment: hoisting the variables is a solution but might cause issues in long term

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly because you there is no connection between the redval in your change color function and the redval in the minusred function , also build the css property as a template string to pass in the values correctly.

the corrected js would be

```
let divcolor = document.getElementById('divcolor');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

function changeColor(redval,green,blue) {
    let color = `rgb(${redval},${green},${blue})`;
    document.getElementById("divcolor").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function minusred() {
    let redval = 0;
    let green = 0;
    let blue = 0;
 
    redval += 100
    changeColor(redval,green,blue);
}


button.addEventListener("click",minusred);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul! This community is very helpful. May I ask a question please? What is the difference between ${redval} and +redval ?

Comment: so what happens behind the seen here is essentially both get converted to the same value i.e string however , template string is a much cleaner way of doing it as you can keep track of you variables and make sure that it gets converted to a string , +redval essentially does is converts the integer to string and appends it . on the bonus you don't get auto complete in IDE for +redval but you do so when you use template string .